# Function for perspective projection of a matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, projection, perspective

Does anyone have a function that returns the perspective projection of a 3x3 matrix in C++?

```
Matrix Perspective()
{
   Matrix m(0, 0, 0);  // Creates identity matrix
   // Perspective projection formulas here
   return m;
}
```

Comment: What is your code for Matrix? That doesn't look like an identity matrix to me.

Comment: Perspective projections act on vectors, not matrices.  As such, I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: Also, the perspective projection requires parameters such as FOV, Aspect Ratio, Near and Far viewing distances and necessarily returns a Homogenized 4x4 Matrix. So I'm even more confused about what you want with a 3x3 Matrix.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one that returns it in a 4x4 matrix, using the formula from the OpenGL [gluPerspective man page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml):

```
static void my_PerspectiveFOV(double fov, double aspect, double near, double far, double* mret) {
    double D2R = M_PI / 180.0;
    double yScale = 1.0 / tan(D2R * fov / 2);
    double xScale = yScale / aspect;
    double nearmfar = near - far;
    double m[] = {
        xScale, 0, 0, 0,
        0, yScale, 0, 0,
        0, 0, (far + near) / nearmfar, -1,
        0, 0, 2*far*near / nearmfar, 0 
    };    
    memcpy(mret, m, sizeof(double)*16);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [OpenCV 2.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) you can almost implement your pseudocode.

There's a `Mat` class for matrices and [`perspectiveTransform`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=perspectivetransform#cvPerspectiveTransform) for perspective projection. And `Mat::eye` returns an identity matrix.

The documentation I've linked to is for OpenCV 1.1 (which is in C) but it's quite simple to infer the correct usage in OpenCV 2.0 (with the `Mat` class) from the manual.